# Error with $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, tidyverse, crosstab, stargazer

So I am trying to produce quick cross tabulation and I ran the following code, where I am essentially trying to view how experience average worker experience per firm varies across regions. Furthermore, I would like to
know what is the ratio_of_subsidized_workers across different firm_revenues. Specifically, how the ratio of subsidized workers varies between a firm falling in the median versus the mean of the distribution for firm revenues.

```
final_dataset %>% 
    group_by(firm_revenue) %>% 
    skim(ratio_of_subsidized_workers)
```

The code is working well, but its not producing what I am looking for.

Would also appreciate any recommendations on how to produce efficient statistics in R

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final_dataset %>% 
    group_by(region) %>% 
    skim(experience_per_firm)
```